# Why doesn't Google Cloud Debugger automatically detect my source code?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-debugger

I've setup Google Cloud Debugger with my site. It is detecting my application. I have run `gcloud debug source gen-repo-info-file` in the root of my project (which is also the root of my Git repo) and I can see the `source-context.json` file on the server. The problem is that when I visit Google Cloud Debugger, I get the message that says `no source code was found`.

Here is the path to my project on the server: `/code/[MY PROJECT]`

Do I need to put this file in a different directory by chance?

Comment: Did you try to manually detect the source code as per this [public document](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/debugging-source-repositories)?

Comment: Yes, I did try that as well but the break points still didn't work. I've only got it to work once, and that was after I tried to manually start the debugger, but it gave me an error saying it was already started. Weird.

Comment: Could you try to redeploy your app from the Git repository, including the source-context.json file ?

Comment: I have tried that multiple times with no success 

Comment: I recommend to open a [bug](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)